# Get backup schedule and retention (short and long term) for SQL Servers using Azure Resource Graph Explorer

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup, kql, retention

I am trying to get the backup schedule and retention for SQL Servers using Azure Resource Graph Explorer. I am unable to find any such information.

The current query that I have is

```
resources
| where type == 'microsoft.sql/servers'
```

I am trying to get the short term and long term backup information for SQL Servers and databases but it doesn't seem to exist in the resources table. I am not sure where this information is stored. I couldn't find anything in recoveryservicesresources table related to PaaS instance of SQL Server backups.

Any ideas?

PS: I am trying to do this using KQL. I know it is possible using PowerShell using 'Get-AzSqlDatabaseBackupShortTermRetentionPolicy' and 'Get-AzSqlDatabaseBackupLongTermRetentionPolicy'.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the backup schedule and retention for SQL Servers using Azure Resource Graph Explorer. I am unable to find any such information.

The backup schedule and retention information for `SQL Servers` and `databases` is not stored in the resources table. However, you can use `Azure Resource Graph Explorer` to query information on backup for your Azure resources.

The `RecoveryServicesResources` table contains most of the backup-related records, such as job details, backup instance details You can use the following Kusto query to list all backup policies used for Azure SQL Servers:

```
RecoveryServicesResources | where  type == 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies'
```

[image]

This query will return all backup policies. However, it will not provide you with the backup schedule and retention information for Azure SQL Server, you can use below `PowerShell` cmdlets to get this information.

```
 Get-AzSqlDatabaseBackupShortTermRetentionPolicy 
Get-AzSqlDatabaseBackupLongTermRetentionPolicy
```

To retrieve the backup schedule and retention information directly from `Azure Resource Graph Explorer` is not currently supported.